# How to wire an LJ18A3-8-Z/BX sensor with an optocoupler to a stock Ender 3?

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, electronics, wiring, inductive-sensor

I have [this](https://m.de.aliexpress.com/item/32719957788.html?trace=wwwdetail2mobilesitedetail) optocoupler.
[image: optocoupler:]

and [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32809655707.html) sensor.
[image: sensor:]

I want to wire them together and use them for auto bed leveling. Note, stock Ender 3 board (Creality v1) has 2 pins for its endstop, not 3, so this:
[image: dosent work:]
won't work

However, I found this diagram:
[image: possibly might work]

My optocoupler is rated for 12 V so I definitely wont attach 24 V to it. However, everything else seems good. So I could only replace the 24 V to 12 V and it would work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inductive Sensor in 24 V machine?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/inductive-sensor-in-24-v-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both diagrams are exactly the same, the difference is the +5 V that is not connected on the bottom diagram (displayed in white, labelled "not used"), but since your endstops do not have a +5 V pin in the socket (only ground, GND, and signal, SIG or S) you don't need to attach it. You should source the +5 V from elsewhere from your board. As the left and right side of the module are separated circuits, you need to power the board with +5 V.

Read [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/10812/) for applying 24 V.